# Matching a sublist in the middle of a list

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm writing a simple parser that uses Scala's pattern matching capabilities.

However it seems to be quite cumbersome to parse something coming *after* a variable number of tokens.

Is there a way for me to do something like the following:

```
def parse(toks: List[Token]) = toks match {
  case FuncDef :: Id(v) :: LeftParen :: { args } :: RightParen :: Nil => 
    // impl goes here
}
```

where `{ args }` is a sublist.

So say if the `Token` list looks like this:

```
List(FuncDef, Id("foo"), LeftParen, Id("x"), Id("y"), Id("z"), RightParen)
```

`{ args }` would then match `Id("x"), Id("y"), Id("z")`

Is this feasible, or do I need to go and do this

```
def parse(toks: List[Token]) = toks match {
  case FuncDef :: Id(v) :: LeftParen :: tail => 
    // impl goes here
}
```

and then go and manually check if `RightParen` appears in the correct place in `tail`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`:+`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.$colon$plus$) matcher to split off the last element of any `Seq`. So the full matching expression would look like this:

```
case FuncDef +: Id(v) +: LeftParen +: args :+ RightParen =>
```

For lists `+:` is basically an equivalent to `::`, so I used it here for symmetry with `:+`.